# Can't pull Row to down

Tags: flutter

I am trying to pull row to end of cross-axis (to bottom of the screen).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(home: HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: FlutterLogo(
                size: 60,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: FlutterLogo(
                size: 60,
                colors: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: FlutterLogo(
              size: 60,
              colors: Colors.cyan,

            ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

[image]

But it's not working. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no height set, so wrap the row in a widget that does
eg.

```
 body: new Column(
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
   mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
     children: [
      Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: FlutterLogo(
            size: 60,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          child: FlutterLogo(
            size: 60,
            colors: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          child: FlutterLogo(
          size: 60,
          colors: Colors.cyan,

        ),
        ),
      ],
    )
      ]
    ),
```

[image: screenshot]
There are other widgets that may be better but it depends on your content
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html

Comment: You use in your example `Column` but not `body: Row(`

Comment: just updated and included alternatives that may also be suitable

Comment: Yes you need to put your row inside the Column because column will fill the entire height of the screen.